# Why wont the question div AND the buttons expand with their content?

Tags: html, css

I tried setting a height: auto for the question div and it would stretch to accomodate its content. I do NOT want overflow: auto or scroll. Is it impossible once I add a certain amount of content? When I put in just one more sentence into the buttons, the buttons get bigger for just one more line. Is this as responsive as it can be?

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body{
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container{
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}

.card{
 margin-top: 3rem;
 height: 400px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 5px solid black;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}


.btn-grid{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
}

.button{
 margin: 0.4rem;
 padding: 0.6rem;
 width: 60%;
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 12px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">
  <div class = "card">
   <div class = "question">
    <div class = "q-content">
     <h2>Who broke into Bryans house?</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id= "answer-buttons" class= "btn-grid">
    <button class= "button">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</button>
    <button class= "button">A homeless khlhjhk</button>
    <button class= "button">kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</button>
    <button class= "button">His ex-wife</button>
   </div>
   <div class = "from">
    <div>From Episode 312</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: add `word-wrap: break-word;` to your .button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to the css for `.button`. This might be what you are after?